# how to not make all hover dropdown boxes open at once?

Tags: html, css, dropdown

Im faced with this annoying issue. i recently positioned my dropdown menu buttons, but after posotioning them they all dropdown at once now. im trying to figure out how to make it so the one you hover over only open and not the others.

here is some of my code.

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```
.move {
    float: left;
    margin: -65px 15px 75px 650px;
}
</style>
<div class="dropdown">
<div class="move">
```

[example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PqSO.jpg)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The  code you've provided is insufficient to solve the problem you've stated. Please provide more of your code.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example In particular you need to show us what you do on hover.

Comment: ive figured it out, just using the wrong the wrong css options to move them,